# if a four digit palindromic number abba/bb equals to an integer,then how many abba are there?

Tags: python, palindrome

**Mursalin takes a four-digit palindromic number 'n' and he deletes it middle two digits to obtain a two-digit number 'm'. If n/m is an integer, how many possible choices for n are there?. The code below returns zero, but what's the problem?**

```
array = []
array2 = []
for i in range(1000,10000):
    if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
        array.append(str(i))
print(array)
for nums in array:
    num = nums[1:3]
    num1 = int(num)
    num2 = int(nums)
    if num1 == 00:
        continue
    num3 = num2/num1
    if str(num3).isdigit():
        array2.append(nums)
print(array2)
print(len(array2))
```

Comment: study your operations around num3

Comment: num3 will return a float always, i want to know how to handle this

Comment: num2//num1 is integer division

Comment: but num2 % num1 == 0 is better way to check

Comment: The question says the middle two digits are deleted to obtain a two-digit number `m`, which means `m` should be what remains of the original 4-digit number, so you should be testing if abba/aa is an integer instead of testing abba/bb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your division `num3 = num2/num1` is not working as if returns a float. You should check if `n/m` is an integer i.e. the rest of the Euclidian's division is equal to zero. Try this:

```
array = []
array2 = []
for i in range(1000,10000):
    if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
        array.append(str(i))
print(array)
for pal in array:
    middle = int(pal[1:3])
    palindrome = int(pal)
    if middle == 00:
        continue
    
    # Check if division's rest is 0, so division's value is integer
    if palindrome % middle == 0:
    array2.append(pal)
print(array2)
print(len(array2))
```